# How to filter array object from another array object?

Tags: arrays, object, filter, methods, arrayobject

I want to make another array object from an array object, suppose I fetched a huge data from an api but I need only particular elements from that object. Exampl:-

```
const mainArray = [
   {id: 1, name: 'John', age: 10},
   {id: 2, name: 'Mark', age: 14},
   {id: 3, name: 'Kevin', age: 15},
   {id: 4, name: 'Julie', age: 16},
   {id: 5, name: 'Liz', age: 10},
   {id: 5, name: 'Emma', age: 11},
   {id: 6, name: 'Robert', age: 13},
]
```

So suppose we have a huge list now I only want `Kevin`, `Emma` & `Mark` to display, for that I need an array of them like this:-

```
const specialKids = [
    {id: 2, name: 'Mark', age: 14},
    {id: 3, name: 'Kevin', age: 15},
    {id: 5, name: 'Emma', age: 11},
 ]
```

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can use the filter method of JS.
Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=de

in your case something like this should be enough:

```
let specialKids[];

specialKids = mainArray.filter(item => item.name === "Mark" || item.name === "Kevin" || item.name === "Emma")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> yourintList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(yourArray));

    for (int i = 0; i < yourintList.lenght; i++) {
        if (yourintList.contains("Kevin")) {
             do something
            }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.